# How to reduce horizontal subplot spacing when tight_layout fails?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm trying to create a single figure in matplotlib with several subplots of different row and column spans, using subplot2grid.

For example, the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as n

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (0, 2))
ax2_2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (0, 3))
ax2_3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (0, 4))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 5), (1, 2), colspan=3) #, sharex=ax2)

xs = n.linspace(0, 2*n.pi, 100)
ax1.plot(xs, n.sin(xs))
ax2.plot(xs, n.cos(xs))
ax2_2.plot(xs, n.tan(xs))
ax2_3.plot(xs, n.sin(xs))
ax3.plot(xs, n.cos(xs))


ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
ax2_2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2_2.set_yticklabels([])
ax2_3.set_xticklabels([])
ax2_3.set_yticklabels([])

# This comes from a separate attempt to make the ticks invisible, but seems to make no change.
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2_2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2_2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2_3.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2_3.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)


fig.set_size_inches(6.5, 2.85)
fig.tight_layout()
# I tried several things here - subplots_adjust improves the vertical spacing a little, but not the horizontal.
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)

fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=100)
```

This makes a figure like:

[image]

The problem is the 3 single-cell subplots in the top right, each of which has only about 70% of the width that would fit. tight_layout otherwise takes care of the spacing nicely, but I can't work out why this space isn't filled, or how to work around it.

So...does anyone know how to do this, making the subplots take the full available width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `subplots_adjust()` the `hspace` parameter will adjust the vertical space, and the `wspace` parameter the horizontal space, so perhaps what you need is:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)
```

Comment: That affects the subplots, but adjusts the spacing for all of them at once, so the 3 plots in the top right are correct but the axis labels and tick labels between the left and right now overlap. It gives a good clue for directions to try though, so thank you!

Comment: @inclement to avoid this overlap you can increase: `ax1.yaxis.labelpad`